# Cannot set a specific key combination as shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys

I want to use the built-in settings application to create a new custom keyboard shortcut and map it to the key combination SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+Z. However, when I get to the dialog that asks me to input the desired combination, pressing SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+Z has no effect.

Other key combinations, such as SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+D, work as intended, the shortcut is created and executes my custom command when the key combination is pressed.

I checked in the shortcut list, and no other shortcut uses SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+Z (but one shortcut uses CTRL+ALT+Z).

The key combination SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+Z appears to do nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem for me on Ubuntu 20.10. Tested with `gnome-calculator`. Mention your precise desktop environment, and perhaps describe more specifically where it goes wrong. Sure the command you enter is valid?

Comment: The command is valid, because it works when I set it to a different key combination. The problem is not the command; rather the settings application does not let me set SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+Z as a shortcut, while for example SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+D works.

Comment: No idea why that would happen. By default, this combination is not in use elsewhere. You could try setting the keyboard combination in dconf-editor under /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/customx/, where customx is one of the folders corresponding with the shortcut definition.